# Check NullPointerException on Recyclerview Item if Child is Empty

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Recyclerview Returns `NullPointerException` if a single bind child value is null or empty.Is there any way to check the empty value so that it won't crash rather don't show the item with empty child value. I tried in my onbind method like this `if(!empty(book.getPck))` but it is not working.How to check this by condition to avoid crash on recyclerview loads

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. Share your code/solution. And add your crash/exception.

Comment: Try this one : if(book.getPck != null)

Comment: I mean if an item value is empty it returns nullpointerexception. In my case if getPck is null it returns the error. so how to check if getpck is null to avaoid crash

Comment: Happy help you :)

Comment: @roy if you have any issue then conatct to us here : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50272/android-kotlin-experts

Comment: if you skip binding if null, you will happen to have a recycled view in a wrong position, you should actually look why its null and have a lyout for null values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some extra condition like:

```
if (book == null || book.getPck == null || empty(book.getPck)) {
    // Do something - is null or empty
} else {
    // Do something - is NOT null
}
```

I don't know return type of `getPck` so don't know how `empty` works.
But when it's `String` you can modify condition to:

```
if (book == null || book.getPck == null || book.getPck.isEmpty()
```

So you verify step by step:

1) Is `book` equals `null`.

2) Is `pck` equals `null`.

3) Is `pck` empty.

Comment: Thanks your solution works too but i can accept one answer so accepted first one